# Does destructuring in ES6 JavaScript reduce memory allocation?

Tags: javascript, web, ecmascript-6, destructuring

Since we skip the places where we don't want to access the element in array destructuring, does that count as less memory allocation? Or skipping a place automatically allocates memory. Example `let [a,,c] = ['a', 'b', 'c']`.
In the above example, are three places stored in the memory?

Comment: This is equivalent to `let a = arr[0]; let b = arr[2];`, so there's no reason to think there's some secret, invisible variable created between `a` and `b`, but the original array (`arr`) still hasn't gone anywhere, so I don't really see any savings between destructuring and not destructuring.

Comment: Memory allocation is implementation-dependant. You can profile your application to find bottlenecks in different browsers. But this looks a lot like micro optimization which is usually a waste of time.